# Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle

Tags: 14.04, kernel, ram, initramfs, dkms

After upgrading to the next linux image, aptitude has outputted the following lines:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic (3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
: Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle.
Will not try to make an initrd.
: Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle.
Will not try to make an initrd.
Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
```

I do have `linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic` installed... but these warning messages are scary. Any ideas what could be the problem?

---

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-37-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14

(I now see that the kernel version is older than the newest one which was installed)

Comment: bad symlink... Check initrd in / It should symlink to /boot/initrd.img* sames goes for vmlinuz.old should symlink to /boot/vmlinuz* If so `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` will fix it.

Comment: `initrd.img` links to `boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic`, and `initrd.img.old` links to `initrd.img.old`. Similar links exist for `vmlinuz`. Is that not how it supposed to be? Still `uname -r` returns `3.16.0-37-generic`.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Pity. a bad symlink would be the easiest reason ;-)

Comment: Seems related to [this dkms bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms/+bug/1647511).

Answer (score 1):

The DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) utility is used to automatically rebuild kernel modules when a new kernel version is installed. The message `DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems)` indicates that there was a problem with the installation of a kernel module using DKMS.

To resolve the issue, you may need to reinstall the problematic kernel module using DKMS or manually install the module. You can also try running the following commands to regenerate the initramfs image and update the module dependency information:

```bash
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo depmod -a
```